# Assign value to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

After loading the page, I'd like to (re-)assign a value to a global variable.  However, it doesn't change after the attempt.

The html is dynamically generated, and contains a select.  Any option can be selected when it is generated, depending on the vehicle id stored in the database.  I need the old (current) vehicle id to close it out when the vehicle is changed.

```
<select id="selVehicle">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option selected value='1'>9999</option>
    <option value='2'>9998</option>
    <option value='3'>9997</option>
</select>
```

In my .js file, I have the declaration of the global variable just before the document.ready():

```
var oldVehicle = -1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").on("blur", function () {
        var tmp = ($(this).val());
        ($(this).val(tmp.toUpperCase()));
    });

    //lots more onblurs and onchanges//

    setOldVehicle();
});

function setOldVehicle() {
    oldVehicle = $('selVehicle option:selected').val();
    alert(oldVehicle);
}
```

When I run it, the alert still says "-1".  How do I update the oldVehicle variable after the page is loaded?

Comment: `#selVehicle`, you didn't have the `#` so the selector didn't work. Also this will actually alert `undefined`.

Comment: Your first hint should be that it should never be "-1" let alone "still" -1.  Test your selector in the browser:  `$("selVehicle").length` - it will be zero.  change the selector and try again `$("#selVehicle").length` and work from there.

Comment: I'd also suggest avoiding global variables. Retrieve values when you need them, and keep the scope to the minimum required.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:  i use the variable in several other functions, and since the "old" value is lost on change, I couldn't think of another way to do it.

Comment: In which case you could try creating your own namespace to avoid polluting global variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here `oldVehicle = $('selVehicle option:selected').val();`

Since your using id you need to pass `#` for id selector

```
oldVehicle = $('#selVehicle option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector  `$('selVehicle option:selected').val();` is missing `"#"` for the ID of the element.

```js
var oldVehicle = -1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":text").on("blur", function() {
    var tmp = ($(this).val());
    ($(this).val(tmp.toUpperCase()));
  });

  //lots more onblurs and onchanges//
  setOldVehicle();
});

function setOldVehicle() {
  oldVehicle = $('#selVehicle option:selected').val();
  alert(oldVehicle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selVehicle">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option selected value='1'>9999</option>
    <option value='2'>9998</option>
    <option value='3'>9997</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ah, another OperatorHeadspaceAndTiming error strikes again.  Either it's Friday, or I need to widen my blinders when I'm trying to track down problems like this.  I was sure I was doing something wrong with the global variable, since I seldom use them.  :/